# Multi module Phalcon Project

Tags: phalcon

I want to create simple multi moudle phalcon project, but it is not working even with on module

I just followed these steps :

**1 : Create Project : phalcon project mod --type=moudles**

**2 : Enable Webtools : phalcon webtools --action=enable**

**3 : Create simple scafoold with webtools**

my project has only one moudle with frontend name.

but when I open the controller url, I get this problem :

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'ControllerBase' not found in C:\wamp\www\mod\apps\frontend\controllers\AdminmenuController.php on line 7
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0171  245464  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0289  262960  handle ( )  ..\index.php:30
3   0.0482  305744  dispatch ( )    ..\index.php:30
4   0.0482  306528  spl_autoload_call ( )   ..\index.php:0
5   0.0482  306640  autoLoad ( )    ..\index.php:0
6   0.0490  362624  Phalcon\Loader->autoLoad( ) ..\index.php:0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with Phalcon dev tools. I don't have it and thus can't give exact directions. However, what you can do is to find the class called `BaseController`. Your `Controller` class is trying to extend from it, and either the namespace or the location doesn't match.

Comment: Yes, I used that, and also namespace, but it do not load Models now

Comment: Don't they have the same problem?

Comment: Unable to load the Users ( My Model Name ) , zemnan farsi ham mitonid harf bezanid ?

Comment: Your users are in that module, so they probably have their own namespace (maybe `\Models`?) Check to see if you're using the model, and if the namespace has been registered in the loader (I.E. `$this->di->getLoader()` should know that namespace). Khoobe ke Irani hastid! Vali age Engilisi benevisim baghie ham mitoonan az rahe halli ke peyda kardid estefade konan :-)